# Need help on possible causes of FTP client timeout

Tags: ftp, iis, c#

My company is hosting a FTP server through Windows IIS. We have a client program (Windows Form program written in C# programming language) which is installed on our client's server for downloading files that are intended for them.

There is one issue happens since a few months ago which is still happening on today. From the print screen provided by the client, the FTPWebRequest seems to be hitting the timeout which I think it is about 1.5 minutes. From the IIS FTP server, I am able to grab the following logs:

```
2021-04-27 07:06:06 <ClientIP> 37079 - 192.9.100.187 21 USER <UserID> 331 0 0 23 21 0 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb -
2021-04-27 07:06:06 <ClientIP> 37079 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 21 PASS *** 230 0 0 21 14 32 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb /
2021-04-27 07:06:06 <ClientIP> 37079 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 21 OPTS utf8+on 200 0 0 58 14 0 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb -
2021-04-27 07:06:07 <ClientIP> 37079 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 21 PWD - 257 0 0 31 5 0 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb -
2021-04-27 07:06:07 <ClientIP> 37079 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 21 CWD Control 250 0 0 29 13 15 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb /Control
2021-04-27 07:06:07 <ClientIP> 37079 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 21 TYPE I 200 0 0 20 8 0 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb -
2021-04-27 07:06:07 <ClientIP> 37079 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 21 PORT <ClientIP>,146,163 200 0 0 30 28 16 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb -
2021-04-27 07:06:07 <ClientIP> 37539 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 20 DataChannelOpened - - 0 0 0 0 0 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb -
2021-04-27 07:06:07 <ClientIP> 37539 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 20 DataChannelClosed - - 0 0 16826 0 0 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb -
2021-04-27 07:06:07 <ClientIP> 37079 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 21 NLST - 226 0 0 16904 6 47 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb /Control
2021-04-27 07:06:07 <ClientIP> 37079 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 21 CWD / 250 0 0 29 7 0 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb /
2021-04-27 07:06:07 <ClientIP> 37079 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 21 CWD Control 250 0 0 29 13 16 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb /Control
2021-04-27 07:06:07 <ClientIP> 37079 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 21 PORT <ClientIP>,138,129 200 0 0 30 28 0 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb -
2021-04-27 07:06:07 <ClientIP> 35457 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 20 DataChannelOpened - - 0 0 0 0 0 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb -
2021-04-27 07:06:07 <ClientIP> 35457 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 20 DataChannelClosed - - 0 0 29462 0 0 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb -
2021-04-27 07:06:07 <ClientIP> 37079 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 21 LIST - 226 0 0 29540 6 32 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb /Control
2021-04-27 07:06:43 <ClientIP> 37079 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 21 CWD / 250 0 0 29 7 16 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb /
2021-04-27 07:06:43 <ClientIP> 37079 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 21 PORT <ClientIP>,142,113 200 0 0 30 28 0 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb -
2021-04-27 07:06:52 <ClientIP> 36465 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 20 DataChannelOpened - - 0 0 0 0 0 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb -
2021-04-27 07:06:52 <ClientIP> 36465 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 20 DataChannelClosed - - 0 0 268 0 0 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb -
2021-04-27 07:06:52 <ClientIP> 37079 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 21 RETR Control/<FileToBeDownloaded> 226 0 0 334 72 9187 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb /Control/<FileToBeDownloaded>
2021-04-27 07:08:23 <ClientIP> 37079 <UserID> 192.9.100.187 21 ControlChannelClosed - - 64 0 608 270 136782 48c11a4b-28e0-4d8c-a590-8ba615e78edb -
```

Is it possible to tell what has gone wrong from the logs above? From the logs I can tell the FTP request is able to reach the server, but somehow the client has waited until the connection timed out.

Comment: My guess is a connection tracking (NAT) issue.  FTP uses 2 channels - one for the connectiin and 1 for data. The direction of initiation of the data connection depends on passive or active mode. You might want to try changing your firewall rules to allow the data connectiin (rather then rely on relatred connection tracking) or switching from passive to active mode.

Comment: I can't see an obvious problem in the log. Some more info about your network might help.

Comment: hi @davidgo, your assumption should be correct, I am thinking to try to change the FTP mode to Passive to see if it works (the current FTP mode used by the client is Active).
Unfortunately, I have to wait for the client (our customer) for an available session for us to configure the FTP settings. I will update here when that is done.